# How to open javascript menu with click & close with mouse out

Tags: javascript, onclick, onmouseover

This is my menu JavaScript function. now my menu open with click & close with click.
i want to open with click & close when mouse leave the button.

```
$("#theme_select").click(function() {
    if (theme_list_open == true) {
        $(".center ul li ul").hide();
        theme_list_open = false;
    } else {
        $(".center ul li ul").show();
        theme_list_open = true;
    }
    return false;
});​
```

im edited with one person & top problem fixed. but when i want to move my mouse to opened menu item menu was closed. see my full script (before change):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var theme_list_open = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function fixHeight () {

        var headerHeight = $("#switcher").height();

        $("#iframe").attr("height", (($(window).height() - 1) - headerHeight) + 'px');

        }

        $(window).resize(function () {

            fixHeight();

        }).resize();

        $("#theme_select").click( function () {

            if (theme_list_open == true) {

            $(".center ul li ul").hide();

            theme_list_open = false;

            } else {

            $(".center ul li ul").show();               

            theme_list_open = true;

            }

            return false;

        });

        $("#theme_list ul li a").click(function () {

        var theme_data = $(this).attr("rel").split(",");

        $("li.purchase a").attr("href", theme_data[1]);
        $("li.remove_frame a").attr("href", theme_data[0]);
        $("#iframe").attr("src", theme_data[0]);

        $("#theme_list a#theme_select").text($(this).text());

        $(".center ul li ul").hide();

        theme_list_open = false;

        return false;

        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Peehaa is that your answer?

Comment: @VoronoiPotato No, it's a question...

Comment: @VoronoiPotato I don't know. Does it look like an answer to you? Is it a bird, is it a plane, is it an answer? It's a comment with the answer in it!

Comment: surry title changed. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this ?

Example.. (Just edit your element selector, if you know jQuery enough)

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu#1</li>
    <span>Sub</span>
    <li>Menu#2</li>
    <span>Sub</span>
</ul>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("ul li").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("showing").next("span").show();
});

$('ul').mouseout(function() {
  $("ul li.showing").removeClass().next("span").hide();
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JcKxV/

**Edited in your case...** Gonna look like..

```
$("#theme_select").click(function() {
    if (theme_list_open == false) {
        $(".center ul li ul").addClass("showing").show();
        theme_list_open = true;
    }
    return false;
});

$("#theme_select").mouseout(function() {
  $(".center ul li ul.showing").removeClass().hide();
    theme_list_open = false;
});
```

or

```
$("#theme_select").click(function() {
    if (theme_list_open == false) {
        $(".center ul li ul").show();
        theme_list_open = true;
    }
    return false;
});

$("#theme_select").mouseout(function() {
    if (theme_list_open == true) {
      $(".center ul li ul").hide();
        theme_list_open = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanck you. im not profesional ples help me how to add this to my codes

Comment: @user1460201 We're not going to do it for you. Please don't post files.

Comment: yes your edited code fixed my problem. but i have another problem. when i want to change my mouse position on opened menu the menu was closed

Comment: edit my orginal question & sent all of script. how to fix : close opene menu whene moving mouse to opened menu. (this scrip when change with your ansver once problem fixet but i have this problem)

Answer (score 1):

[What @PeeHaa is trying to say, is] Use the `jQuery` [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

```
$("#theme_select").click(function() {
    if ($("#theme_select").is(":visible")) {
        $(".center ul li ul").hide();
    } else {
        $(".center ul li ul").show();
    }
    return false;
});​


$("#theme_select").hover(function() {
     //Do Nothing
    },function(){
        $(".center ul li ul").hide(); //Mouse leave
});​
```

The first function represents the code that executes when the mouse hovers over theme_select. The second function represents the code that executes when the mouse leaves theme_select.

Comment: 1- i need to open with click, no mouse over.